# Запретить переход на новую строку

Tags: css, html

Как отменить переход на новую строку после блока div?

```
 <div class="product-price">
   <p>19.99€</p>
 </div>
 <p>/gab.</p>
```

Comment: `.product-price {display: inline-block;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не только в `div`, параграфы тоже блочные:

```css
.product-price,
.product-price > p, /*Параграф внутри div*/
.product-price + p  /*Параграф после div*/
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-price">
   <p>19.99€</p>
 </div>
 <p>/gab.</p>
```

Вероятно, проще использовать строчные элементы:

```css
.product-price {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-price">
   <span>19.99€</span>
</div>
<span>/gab.</span>
```